# Reliably find Notepad++ window handle

Tags: winapi, notepad++, sendmessage, scintilla

I want to use some SCINTILLA `SendMessage()` to an open notepad window(s), but I am not sure how to reliably get Notepad++ opened window handles.

Comment: What is not reliable with FinWindow/EnumWindows?

Comment: Please help find right parameters for Find/EnumWindows

Comment: You should show what you have tried so far

Comment: I try to improve my answer skills. Please tell me why you approved but not upvoted. I will do better next time.

Comment: I did not know I must do that. How about source-code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Spy++

Main Notepad++ window class name is "`Notepad++`".
Scintilla window class name is "`Scintilla`"

[image]